# How can I make text white for all text after a certain text length has been reached inside of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery.dataTables fn.Filter which searches a given table with regex. I want hidden attributes for some cells in the table so that I can filter cells by group even if the text for those cells is not related. In order to do this, I figured I must make text (that classifies that cell into a group) invisible to the user but visible to fn.filter. The background of the table is white, so white text will be the solution here.

The structure of the function that I have right now is as follows:

```
function add_hidden_attribute(cell_text, cell_index, product_parent){

    //get length of cell_text
    var text_length = cell_text.length;

    //make text white for all text after text length + 1


    //add product_parent after cell_text
    index = cell_index;
}
```

Could someone help me out a bit more?

Comment: It sounds like a very creative approach. Could you please give an example for a row <tr><td>...</td></tr>?

Comment: I use a similar approach in one of my apps. Just tell me which version of dataTables you are using. There was a large change recently. Then I can provide you with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Orthogonal Data](http://datatables.net/manual/orthogonal-data) feature for this purpose. It allows you to define data which is searchable but not visible to the user. For example (taken and simlplified from the link):

```
<tr>
    <td data-search="Tiger Nixon">T. Nixon</td>    
</tr>
```

Just add your additional info as `data-search` attribute, `Datatables` will handle the rest for you.